# Change width of the Activity's layout based on MotionEvent

Tags: android, android-layout

What I am trying to do is to Override the dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) method, get the actions, calculate the movement, and then show the bottom part based on the movements.

Here is my basic idea:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int action = ev.getActionMasked();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mDownX = ev.getRawX();
            mDownY = ev.getRawY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float deltaY = ev.getRawY() - mDownY;
            Log.d(TAG, "delta y: " + deltaY);
            if (deltaY < -50f) {
                // show bottom part
            }
            if (deltaY > 50f) {
                // close bottom part
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My question is: What should I use to change the width of this Activity's width and show the bottom part?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The bottom part of what??? By the way, you can't change the width of the Activity.

Comment: @Merlevede The bottom of the Activity. Say you set some view GONE at first, then you want to hide/show it according to the MotionEvent

Comment: I don't get it. To show/hide a view just change its visibility.

Comment: @Merlevede right. But what if some animation is needed? Say based on the movement, slowly show / close the view?

Comment: Well, if you had mentioned the word 'animation' in your question....

Comment: @Merlevede That's my bad. And you have given good hints :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I love layout hacks.

For this example, I will have a top section and a bottom section, which is the section you would like to expose on motion event.

On your swipe function, set the visibility of the bottomBlock to visible, the `animateLayoutChanges` will make it look like it's sliding up.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout
```